# image object orientation and rotation using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have almost 1000 images of similar dataset all of them have black background and an object (skin cancer mole) . Now the problem is clear i.e the objects are in different orientation I want the objects in all images with same orientation.

MATLAB code will be recomended.

Comment: What did you try up to mow?

Comment: 3d or 2d images? rigid, affine or non-linear registration? if you know how to answer these questions you will also find toolboxes for such.

Comment: work with "regionprops" first thing is that it needs binary or gray level image, second how then I convert to rgb and rotate with respect to specific orientation

Comment: Sorry but I think you should first understand you data, what you need to know, and how to solve it. SO is suppose to help you with the coding but not to do everything for you.

Comment: Recommended code is one thing.  Giving it to you is another.  You clearly have not tried anything, so we are not inclined to try either.  What I would recommend you do is find an image that has the orientation you want, then do keypoint detection, then image registration to find the angle of rotation from the target image to the base image you're comparing to.  This article should get you started: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale.html .  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found:
  Check the two images of skin lesion mole shown below:

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

We assume that it comes from loop on folder(1000 images) in which they are at:

```
Code:

  % I1= first image
    I=imread(I1);    %% Image input 
    BW = im2bw(I,0.004);

  %%%%%  Getting the biggest region (because if segmentation give unclear results)

  [L, num] = bwlabel(BW, 8);
  count_pixels_per_obj = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
  [~,ind] = max(count_pixels_per_obj);  
  biggest_region = (L==ind);

  %%%%%% 

   %%% getting orientation

   s  = regionprops(biggest_region, 'Orientation');
   data=s.Orientation;

   %%% Orientation end

    Y = imrotate(I, -data, 'loose', 'bilinear');

      figure; 
      imshow(Y)

  %%% Now the rotated image will be shown as
```

[image: rotated image]

```
  %% Now write the image in any other folder
  %% that have all images aligned

  imwrite(Y, 'test.jpg'); 

 %% Hope it will save time for other. Thanks
```